# How do i assign a RadioButton to a RadioGroup in XE2?

Tags: delphi, radio-button, delphi-xe2

Don't hate (or devote) me on this silly question, but i noticed on XE2 it has changed, i try to drop a new RadioButton to a RadioGroup and i notice it is actually NOT a part of that group, why ?

and what is this TStrings i need to write ? it's kind of hard for me to control it like that.

Comment: Did you install a documentation?

Comment: @user539484 to be honest, i never install it, but from now on, i will. :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot manually add a [TRadioButton](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TRadioButton) to a TRadioGroup. The [TRadioGroup](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TRadioGroup) control has always worked in this way. You must use its `Items` property to add the radio buttons.

The Embarcadero documentation says

> To add radio buttons to a TRadioGroup, edit the Items property in the
>   Object Inspector. Each string in Items makes a radio button appear in
>   the group box with the string as its caption. The value of the
>   ItemIndex property determines which radio button is currently
>   selected.

So you can use the Object Inspector to edit the `Items` property or writing code like this:

```
RadioGroup1.Items.Add('Option 1');
RadioGroup1.Items.Add('Option 2');
RadioGroup1.Items.Add('Option 3');
RadioGroup1.Items.Add('Option 4');
RadioGroup1.Items.Add('Option 5');
```

Finally to check which radio button is selected use the `ItemIndex` property like so

```
if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex>=0 then
  ShowMessage(RadioGroup1.Items[RadioGroup1.ItemIndex]);
```

Comment: how can i add an image (from a TImageList) near the Radio button ?

Comment: Use a group box to which you add radio buttons **and** your images.